# How to remove top border for one element in a list

Tags: css, navigation, html-lists

I am building my navigation with an unordered list:

```
<ul class="nav nav--block nav--banner multi-dropdown"><li class="first current"><a href="http://localhost/huayang/en/" title="Home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="news/" title="News">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="students" title="Students">Students</a></li>
    <li><a href="locations" title="Locations">Locations</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact" title="Contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li class="last"><a href="about-us" title="About us">About us</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want my navigation to look like:
[image]

Notice how the top border is gone for the current navigation item? This is what I don't manage to achieve.
In order to have the top/bottom border apply to the whole navigation, I have to set it to the ul element. In that case, I don't know how to remove the border for the active li item.

My CSS:

```
.nav.nav--block {

  border-top: 1px solid $medium-grey;
  border-bottom: 1px solid $medium-grey;

  &>li.current {
    background-color: $light-grey;
    border-top: 1px solid $light-grey;
    border-left: 1px solid $medium-grey;
    border-right: 1px solid $medium-grey;
  }


  &> li > a {
    padding: 12px 35px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: $dark-grey;
  }
}
```

Which gives me:

[image]

Any idea how to solve my problem?

Comment: can you please give a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to do something simple like this.

```
.currentItem { padding-bottom: 6px; /*Increase padding by width of border */
    margin-bottom: -6px; /* Offset by that amount, or use relative positioning which may be better. */
    position: relative; /* This method OR margin offset */
    bottom: -6px; /* This method OR margin offset */
}
```

I'm sure there are many others, some more elegant. But these should work.

If it's top border, which I see now, you will do the opposite:

```
.currentItem { padding-top: 1px; /*Increase padding by width of border */
    margin-top: -1px; /* Offset by that amount, or use relative positioning which may be better. */
    position: relative; /* This method OR margin offset */
    top: -1px; /* This method OR margin offset */
}
```

Comment: Awesome, works like a charm. I prefer the margin-top solution because the  position relative one shifts the navigation item up.